# Scrollbar on parent window is missing when fancybox is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar, fancybox-2

I am loading ajax response in my fancybox. But the moment fancybox opens, the scrollbar on the parent window disappears. Not sure if this is the default behavior of the fancybox. Scrollbar is not seen until I close the fancybox. I want to see the scrollbar on the parent window. Please let me know if I am missing something in my fancybox code. Thanks!

j.fancybox({

```
      content  : fb,
      autoSize : false,
      scrolling : 'no',
      padding : 0,
      autoResize : false,
      autoHeight : false,
      autoWidth  : false,
      closeBtn   : false,
      beforeLoad : function() {
        this.width = document.getElementById("jqi").offsetWidth;
        this.height = document.getElementById("jqi").offsetHeight;
        this.minWidth = document.getElementById("jqi").offsetWidth;
        this.minHeight = document.getElementById("jqi").offsetHeight;
      }
```

});

Comment: fancybox sets an calss that disables scrolling on parten window... what excatly is your question?

Comment: I want to be able to scroll the parent window. Though I cannot do any action on the parent window until I close fancybox, I want to atleast see what is on the window. So, I need the scroll bar.

Comment: add this option `helpers: {overlay: {locked: false} }` http://jsfiddle.net/L1whuee0/1/